# Script for counting multiple different entries in selected cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I have found this script for sheets and modified it a little, so that it looks for values in selected cells, counts them separately and returns a browser message with a result (like  "100":12(times), "unavailable":5, "delayed":4 etc). Can someone help me modify that script so it can also separately parse different values\strings in a single cell (separated by some specific symbol, for example). Also, a way for it to count\return only a marked values, and then adding them in result as a sums of marked values.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Count Stuff", functionName: "countStuff"}];
  ss.addMenu("aQ", menuEntries);
}

function countStuff() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      r = s.getActiveSelection(),
      v = r.getValues(),
      d = {},
      i = v.length - 1,
      t;

  while (i > 0) {
    if ("" === (t = v[i--][0])) {
      continue;
    }

    d[t] ? d[t]++ : (d[t] = 1);
  }

  t = "";

  for (v in d) {
    t += v + ":" + d[v] + "\n";
    i++;
  }

  i !== 0 && s.getRange(r.getLastRow() + 1, r.getLastColumn() - r.getNumColumns() + 1).setValue(i);

  Browser.msgBox(i === 0 ? "No values selected!" : t);

  delete s, r, v, d, i, t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a counting function that splits the entried by comma `,`

It proceeds in two steps: (1) Flatten the values, by concatenating the rows together; in the process, each entry of a row is converted to a string and split by commas. (2) Counts the entries; with a flat array this is easy. The counts are kept in an object, and the formatting for message box is done by `JSON.stringify`

```
function countStuff() {
  var v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getValues();
  var count = {};

  if (!v.map) {
    Browser.msgBox("Select a range to count");
    return;
  }

  var flat = v.reduce(function(a, row) {
    return a.concat(row.reduce(function(a, entry) {
      return a.concat(entry.toString().split(','));  // adjust split as needed
    }, []));
  }, []);

  for (var i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    count[flat[i]] = count[flat[i]] + 1 || 1;
  }

  Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(count));
}
```

If splitting is not required, the computation of flat array is simplified to

```
  var flat = v.reduce(function(a, row) {
    return a.concat(row);
  });
```